# When an Oauth provider is used to delegate authentication, then does the appserver return any token to the caller?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt

In Oauth and Openidconnect, the appserver endpoint invocation starts the Oauth flow and the app server gets the token from the auth server and is able to pass the token to resource server to access resources (delegation) on behalf of the resource owner.

The token exchange happens between the app server and resource server, and the token never arrives at the end users browser.

I'm working on a web api (aka app server) that will be consumed by a mobile app. There is no other server involved. Presently the login endpoint returns a signed JWT token to the user if correct credentials are supplied (validate against the db). User places this token in the header of the subsequent request.

Assuming I don't want to have a user db and validate logins, and instead delegate the auth check to another service like azure b2c or firebase (that use the Oauth), then I assume the flow is like given below:

1. Api registered the firebase/azure b2c (let's call this the provier) clientid, secret.
2. User invokes login endpoint of my api
3. The api invokes the provider's Oauth flow.
4. User gets popup to authenticate with the provider.
5. Eventually the provider will send the token (containing the claim like username) to the api (aka app server)

Does the user get back any token? Otherwise, when the user makes subsequent endpoint calls, then how is the endpoint able to identify who is this user and whether he is already authenticated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is okay to send back the access token to the user , but from the security best practise 's point of view , it is better not to do it which I quote the reasons as follow from [this](https://curity.io/resources/learn/spa-best-practices/#backend-for-frontend-bff):

> Because of the issues outlined above, the best security recommendation
> for an SPA is to avoid keeping tokens in the browser at all. This can
> be achieved with the help of a lightweight back-end component, often
> described as a Backend-For-Frontend.
>
> The backend component can then be configured as a confidential OAuth
> client and used to keep tokens away from the browser. It can either be
> stateful and keep tokens in custom storage, or stateless and store the
> tokens in encrypted HTTP-only, same-site cookies. Whichever variant is
> chosen, the backend component creates a session for the SPA, using
> HTTP-only, secure, same-site cookies, thus enabling a high level of
> security. Such cookies cannot be read by scripts and are limited to
> the domain of the SPA. When combined with strict Content Security
> Policy headers, such architecture can provide a robust protection
> against stealing tokens

Also from [here](https://curity.io/resources/learn/oauth-for-mobile-apps-best-practices/#using-a-system-browser-component) ,they suggest for mobile app 's OAuth2 best practise , it should perform the OAuth flow inside a system browser component.

Comment: Can you give some more advise regarding `when the user makes subsequent endpoint calls, then how is the endpoint able to identify who is this user and whether he is already authenticated?`

Comment: You can try to google something like `how cookie session management` to get the ideas of how does it work

Comment: So you are saying that cookie session management is not the responsibility of the Oauth. Oauth will give my api backend the token and its the backend's duty to store it maybe into a session (which sends cookie to user pointing to the session id) to ensure it can be used in subsequent endpoint invocation by the user?

Comment: Correct. OAuth does not define anything about how to manage the user session. It is  up to you to design how to manage it . And for the stateless HTTP protocol , we usually manage the user session by the use of cookie.